# Kickstarter.com "top"-bar small images HOW TO?

Tags: jquery, css

I've been trying to make my version of Kickstarter.com's top-bar cool-looking small images showoff - without any luck.

I've tried to position items absolutely, but no matter what I do it's just not "working".

Here is what've done:

```
$('#holder .box').each(function(n){
   var pLeft = $(this).position().left;

   $(this).css({
     position: 'absolute',
     left: pLeft
   });
});
```

But then all the items stack on top of each other.

BTW: I KNOW this is not enough to do the trick, but I need help to get further from this issue. With other words: I'm STUCK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see something that is cool and you wonder "How did they do that?" ... what should your first response be?

Look at it in Firebug. Or Chrome's dev tools. Or something. See what the HTML structure is. See what the CSS is that's applied to everything. If there's a CSS rule that you don't understand what it does, just turn it off temporarily or mess with the value. Use Firebug's ability to manipulate stuff live to your advantage.

In this case, it's actually not that difficult. The items inside just use images that are `float:left; width:120px; height:90px` - there are a lot of them. The wrapper is 2640 pixels wide and centered, so it's `position:absolute; margin-left:50%; width:2640px; left:1320px`.

Comment: Thanks dude. I know. But I thought I had to do something with JS since there's more images the bigger the screen you have. Also I thought I needed JS since theres some images that's half in both left and right side.

Comment: Nope! :) It's just a really wide div that's centered. Just zoom out and you'll see!

Comment: I see! awww... I've wasted 3 hours of my day looking dumb -.-' well.. thanks Anthony :)

Comment: "He who asks a question is a fool for five minutes. He who does not ask a question remains a fool forever." -- ancient Chinese proverb :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/sfkzY/

Not sure why you're trying to do your layout using JS?

Answer (score 0):

It's a grid, so I'd go for a table, like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UE9nm/).